# How do I connect to a fake SMTP server using Loopback

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, loopbackjs

This similar to to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620394/how-do-i-setup-smtp-with-loopback-io), but intstead I am trying to connect to this fake smtp-server

https://www.npmjs.com/package/smtp-sink

I run this server using `npm i smtp-sink` and `smtp-sink` and it seems fine

Here is how I have configured my datasource:

```
  "emailDataSource": {
    "connector": "mail",
    "transports": [{
      "type": "smtp",
      "host": "localhost",
      "secure": false,
      "port": 1025,
      "tls": {
        "rejectUnauthorized": false
      }
    }]
  }
```

and sending the email through an endpoint as such: (this 9is inside a remote method)

```
var options = {

  to: "bla@bla.com",
  subject: "subject",
  text: "text",
  html: "html"
};

app.models.Email.send(options, function (err, mail) {
  cb(null || err, null || mail);
});
```

However, I now get the following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "Error",
    "status": 500,
    "message": "Data command failed",
    "code": "EENVELOPE",
    "response": "503 Bad sequence: MAIL expected",
    "responseCode": 503,
    "stack": "Error: Data command failed\n    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/Users/admin/Documents/Projects/otogo/otogo-api-server/build/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/nodemailer/node_modules/nodemailer-smtp-transport/node_modules/smtp-connection/src/smtp-connection.js:388:15)\n    at SMTPConnection._actionDATA (/Users/admin/Documents/Projects/otogo/otogo-api-server/build/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/nodemailer/node_modules/nodemailer-smtp-transport/node_modules/smtp-connection/src/smtp-connection.js:909:30)\n    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Documents/Projects/otogo/otogo-api-server/build/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/nodemailer/node_modules/nodemailer-smtp-transport/node_modules/smtp-connection/src/smtp-connection.js:885:22)\n    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/Users/admin/Documents/Projects/otogo/otogo-api-server/build/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/nodemailer/node_modules/nodemailer-smtp-transport/node_modules/smtp-connection/src/smtp-connection.js:507:16)\n    at SMTPConnection._onData (/Users/admin/Documents/Projects/otogo/otogo-api-server/build/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/nodemailer/node_modules/nodemailer-smtp-transport/node_modules/smtp-connection/src/smtp-connection.js:357:10)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)\n    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:764:14)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)\n    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:426:10)\n    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:422:5)"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @AmitGupta I ended up using https://mailtrap.io/ as a fake smtp server, it was pretty easy to connect to.

Comment: Regarding to the answer below, were you able to get it working? I am trying to send email for forgotten password for default loopback `User` model, but can't get it to work...I have setup Gmail as @superkhau suggested but don't know how to setup `User` password reset call

Answer (score 0):

Look at my example here on how to send emails: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-faq-email

As for the NPM package, I've never used it so I can't help you there.

Comment: link you mentioned is broken & gives 404

Comment: The email example got moved to https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-app-logic#add-an-email-connector